# Java: class equivalent for an enum

Tags: java, enums

If there is an enum,

```
public enum Animal {
   DOG,
   CAT;
}
```

If I'm understanding enums correctly, we can convert them in equivalent class, something like -

```
public class Animal {
   private static final DOG = 1;
   private static final CAT = 2;
}
```

Is this the correct representation, or I'm missing anything here?

Thanks.

Comment: No this is not actual representation !!! [Check this Documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enums.html)

Comment: @NaveenRamawat , Not it is not , check out Pshemo Answer !

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly. Here is how it will look like:

```
public class Animal extends Enum<Enum<Animal>> {
   public static final Animal DOG = new Animal("DOG", 0);
   public static final Animal CAT = new Animal("CAT", 1);
   private static final Animal[] values = new Animal[] {DOG, CAT};

   private Animal(String name, int ordinal) {super(name, ordinal);}
   public static Animal valueOf(String name) {return Enum.valueOf(Animal.class, name)}
   public Animal[] values() {return values;}
}
```

Class `java.lang.Enum` holds `ordinal` and `name` and provides methods that can access them.

Comment: Your constructor seems stale with the recent changes you made.

Answer (score 3):

No, your code shows how things ware organized before `enum` was added in Java 1.5.

- Your enum values needs to be `public` not `private` because you want to make them accessible everywhere.
- Also they value is instance of your enum class, not integer (you may want to invoke some methods on these instances like `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(120);` where you invoke `toMinutes` on instance `SECONDS`)

So your code looks more like

```
public class Animal extends Enum<Animal>{
    public static final Animal DOG = new Animal();
    public static final Animal CAT = new Animal();

    //rest of code added by compiler, like 
    // - making constructor private
    // - handling `ordinal()` 
    // - adding `valueOf(String) ` and `values()` methods
}
```

Comment: Getting compilation error - classes cannot directly extend java.lang.Enum, any resolutions?

Comment: That is correct. Enum is class which can be extended only by code generated by compiler via `enum YourClass` (which will produce `class YourClass extends Enum<YourClass>{...}`. You can't avoid it.

Comment: So do you mean the way in the class above is can't be compiled and hence can't be used?

Comment: I mean that result of compiling your enum would be similar to compiling this class (if compiler would allow it).

Comment: Ohk, I was trying to avoid enums at all for some specific case, where one of the element in enum needs generalization (which should be with instance), and hence was trying using non-static way via creating my own class. I know I should be more clear in question but I was trying to collect some raw data first.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve there can be way around (maybe even by using enum). Consider posting second question where you will describe in detail what you want to do and what stops you from finishing your task.